# AngularJS input directive applying and removing format on blur&focus

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I am trying to create this input directive, where you type in 8digits number and blur, it applys 'yyyy/mm/dd' format ONLY on viewvalue. The modelValue must remain in 'yyyymmdd' format.  I came up with codes on below, but I am lost of how to use the ngModelController at this point.  Any help would be great.

```
'use strict';

function applyFormat(value) {
  return value.substring(0, 4) + "/" + value.substring(4, 6) + "/" + value.substring(6, 8);
}

function removeFormat(value) {
  return value.match(/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/g).join('');
}

angular.module('app').directive('dateInput', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      dateFormat: '@'
    },
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) => {

      if (!ctrl) return;

      // onBlur - make 8 digits number into yyyy/mm/dd format
      elem.bind('blur', () => {

        ctrl.$setViewValue(applyFormat(ctrl.$modelValue));

        ctrl.$parsers.push(() => {
          return removeFormat(ctrl.$viewValue);
        })

        ctrl.$formatters.push(() => {
          return applyFormat(ctrl.$modelValue);
        })

      })

      // onFocus - make yyyy/mm/dd styled data to 8digits num yyyymmdd
      elem.bind('focus', () => {
        if (!ctrl.$modelValue) return;

        ctrl.$formatters.push(() => {
          return removeFormat(ctrl.$viewValue);
        })

      })
    }
  }
})
```

the use of directive would be like this
`<input type="text" date-input>`

this is what I want to accomplish with directive, with view&model values all set. http://plnkr.co/edit/kZu5Ko?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, `$render()` was missing in my code.
Also, $parsers & $formatters only had to be set once.
I hope this will help others struggling through ngModelController.

```
'use strict';

function applyFormat(value) {
  return value.substring(0, 4) + "/" + value.substring(4, 6) + "/" + value.substring(6, 8);
}

function removeFormat(value) {
  return value.match(/[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*/g).join('');
}

angular.module('app').directive('dateInput', () => {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope: {
      dateFormat: '@'
    },
    link: (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) => {

      if (!ctrl) return;

      ctrl.$parsers.push(() => {
        return removeFormat(ctrl.$viewValue);
      })

      ctrl.$formatters.push(() => {
        return applyFormat(ctrl.$modelValue);
      })

      // onBlur - make 8 digits number into yyyy/mm/dd format
      elem.bind('blur', () => {
        if (!ctrl.$modelValue || !ctrl.$viewValue) return;

        ctrl.$setViewValue(applyFormat(ctrl.$modelValue));
        ctrl.$render();

      })

      // onFocus - make yyyy/mm/dd styled data to 8digits num yyyymmdd
      elem.bind('focus', () => {
        if (!ctrl.$modelValue || !ctrl.$viewValue) return;

        ctrl.$setViewValue(ctrl.$modelValue);
        ctrl.$render();

      })
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can just remove the "/" when you need to work with data
when you have like first day of the month, you should wride 2015/12/1 not 2015/12/01  keep that in mind

Comment: that sounds easy but I have to integrate with other directives so sadly that is not an option for me. ty.